# iOS: Pop-up menu does not behave in accordance with first responder set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have several objects inheriting `UIView` in my application that are tracking taps on them and presenting Copy/Paste pop-up if they contain some specific data. When pop-up is presented I change the appearance of the object as well.

This is how it is implemented:

```
- (void)viewDidReceiveSingleTap:(NSNotification *)n {
    MyObject *mo = (MyObject *)n.object;

    [mo becomeFirstResponder];
    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu update];

    [menu setTargetRect:CGRectMake(...) inView:mo];

    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

`MyObject` class, in turn, defines `canBecomeFirstResponder:` and `canResignFirstResponder:` as always returning `YES`. `becomeFirstResponder:`, `resignFirstResponder:`, and `canPerformAction:withSender:` is also defined accordingly (this is where I change the appearance of the object).

This is what goes wrong:

I tap object 1. The method `viewDidReceiveSingleTap:` above is getting called, and the object's `canBecomeFirstResponder:` and `becomeFirstResponder:` are getting called too. The pop-up menu is displayed as expected.

I tap another object 2. `viewDidReceiveSingleTap:` is called again and here's where the trouble starts. First, `canResignFirstResponder:`, `resignFirstResponder:` of object 1 are called, but not always, and I can't figure out the pattern. `canBecomeFirstResponder:` and `becomeFirstResponder:` of object 2 are called properly, but the pop-up menu does not relocate. It just disappears (though in the `viewDidReceiveSingleTap:` I clearly call `setMenuVisible:YES`). In order to make it appear, I have to tap object 2 (or any other) again -- in this case I can see from the debugger that object 2 was set as a first responder, it's just the pop-up that wasn't appearing.

What am I doing wrong? Any clues on relation between pop-up menu visibility and first responder?

Comment: +1 for well written question.  Have you tried explicitly resigning first responder status of any possible outstanding popups at the beginning of your method? Might help, but never ran into this problem thoroughly, hence the comment.

Comment: @Jesse: the trouble is that viewDidReceiveSingleTap in general does not know which object is the first responder currently. I could try detecting that but this looks like a hack -- callbacks should always be invoked, otherwise something is wrong with my code.

Comment: yes well i've had a kind of similar issue with some text fields back in 2.0 before they reworked, and i used basically a hack and called resignFirstResponder: on all the other possibilities and it worked fine. messy, but preferable to not working i think.

Comment: @Jesse: have you even encountered anything similar in 3.0+? Maybe with the same old code.

Comment: @Sergey: nothing that comes to mind, sorry.

Comment: Instead of calling resignFirstResponder on all other possibilities, would it be much better to just always set some dummy view as first responder then resign it immediately at the beginning of the method? Just so you're sure no one is registered as first responder at the time you need to assign it to the right object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when you tap anywhere except on the menu, it does an animated hide of itself. That hide is taking precedence over your animated show. So, if you tap a view to make the menu show, tap anywhere else (either on another one of those views or just anywhere else), and then tap another one of those views, the menu will show every time.

I think there's a good argument to be made for keeping that behavior, because it's the standard behavior that users will expect. But, of course, you have a better idea of what makes sense for your app. So, here's the trick:

```
[menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Here's the code I used to try it out:

```
@implementation MenuView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    UIMenuItem *item = [UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                 action:@selector(test)];
    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
    [item release];
    [menu setMenuItems:items];

    [menu setTargetRect:self.bounds inView:self];

    [menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"Test!");
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return action == @selector(test);
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    NSLog(@"Can become called");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canResignFirstResponder {
    NSLog(@"Can resign called");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    [super becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Become called");

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "That hide is taking precedence over your animated show" -- do you know by any chance, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't think it's documented; it's just something I learned through experience.